# Options for various auth strategies for express API

Tags: cookies, api, oauth2, node.js

OK, I need some help with this:

I am creating a Node express API, and I want to support the following auth strategies:

1. Cookie or JWT based authentication that supports MFA (OTP, email, and SMS), for clients (web/mobile) that are internal.
2. OAuth2/OIDC (again with MFA), for third-party clients, combined with API keys for identifying registered clients.
3. API keys, for secure clients who will be accessing read-only data or functionality via the API

I assume these strategies are sound in general (if not, I'd like to know what the issues are).

I don't want to use 3rd-party paid auth services such as Auth0 or Okta. I'd also prefer to use middleware, or a library, instead of a service (even if free). I could write my own middleware, but I fear creating something that has serious security weaknesses.

So what are my options? Passport would seem like a good option, but I am worried that many passport plugins are not vetted, or are they?. It seems anybody can just write and publish a passport plugin.

Comment: This looks like you want a product recommendation (but preferable a free one). Product recommendations are off-topic here.

Comment: I'm not looking for product recommendations. I'm asking: what are the technologies available for doing X, and maybe an idea of their pros and cons.

Comment: *"I don't want to use 3rd-party paid auth services ... "* - this is a restriction based on the business model (paid vs free, library vs. service,... ), not on technology. That's why your question looks like asking for product recommendations, not for technologies.

Comment: No, my restriction is based on architectural requirements. The system I'm building requires auth functionality to be integrated with it in source code form, not as an external service dependency.

Comment: This contradicts in my opinion your question which states that you *prefer* middleware/library, not that services are not allowed. Also, paid does not necessarily mean closed source either.

Comment: Well, yes maybe I should have said "require" instead of "prefer".